# Dockerize compatible framework version

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

i want to dockerize my microservices. But i getting this error.

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64) was not
> found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>   6.0.3 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or
>   SDK. The specified framework can be found at:
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64

And this is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.3 as build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY Shared/FreeCourse.Shared/*.csproj Shared/FreeCourse.Shared/
COPY Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/
RUN dotnet restore Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj 
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.3 as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","FreeCourse.Services.Catalog.dll"]
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your app is specified to use SDK 5.0.0 - you have to update it to 6.0.3 or change which SDK image is used for compilation.

Comment: I changed my dockerfile to this. But i got the same error.

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY Shared/FreeCourse.Shared/*.csproj Shared/FreeCourse.Shared/
COPY Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/
RUN dotnet restore Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj 
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish Services/Catalog/FreeCourse.Services.Catalog/*.csproj -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-bullseye-slim as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","FreeCourse.Services.Catalog.dll"]

Comment: If you get exactly the same error it still is running with a newer SDK version in the image.

Comment: Can you share the list of asp.net core runtimes Installed in your local machine ?